# center cards but with a left justify?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an unknown number of fixed-size cards displayed in a fluid container.  I want the rows centered but the problem comes in when there's an uneven number of cards to fill a row. It'll center two cards underneath a row display 5 cards.  I'd like for those 2 cards to justify to the left so everything remains vertically inline.  If I align everything to the left, then I can end up with an uneven margin on the left and right side of the outer columns. For instance, the screen width might only have room to display 4 cards in a row, but the spacing to the right left to fill could be anywhere from 0 to 300px (the size of a card). Hopefully that makes sense. If not I'll draw pictures to illustrate what I mean.

https://www.codeply.com/p/pOnFgE1lTs

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-10 offset-md-1'>
            <div class='card-deck'>

                <!-- repeat this block for X-number of cards -->
                <div class="card mb-4 game-card mx-auto">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="#">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        <h4 class="card-title text-center">Game Title</h4>
                        <p class="card-text" style="text-align:justify">title here</p>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">View</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.game-card{max-width:300px;width:300px;min-width:300px}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this example which I think will meet my needs. I'm not really sure what its doing yet, I've never dealt with scss before.

```
// Bootstrap 4 breakpoints & gutter
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 576px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1200px
) !default;

$grid-gutter-width: 30px !default;

// number of cards per line for each breakpoint
$cards-per-line: (
    xs: 1,
    sm: 2,
    md: 3,
    lg: 4,
    xl: 5
);

@each $name, $breakpoint in $grid-breakpoints {
    @media (min-width: $breakpoint) {
        .card-deck .card {
            flex: 0 0 calc(#{100/map-get($cards-per-line, $name)}% - #{$grid-gutter-width});
        }
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/migli/pen/OQVRMw

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using Bootstrap's `.row-cols` class rather than trying to alter the way `.card-deck` has been written, particularly if that side of things isn't familiar to you. [Grid Cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/#grid-cards) (which use `.row-cols`) are relatively new to Bootstrap. They allow you to choose how many columns / cards you want on each row based on screen size. Columns will wrap and any incomplete row will have its columns / cards built from left to right which sounds like what you are trying to achieve.

As you've got fixed width cards which you want to sit centrally within their columns you either need to add `.mx-auto` to the cards or add `margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;` to your `.game-card` class. I would prefer the latter but up to you on that front.

Check out the codepen below for coded example...

https://codepen.io/the_real_andrew/pen/vYOVMzo

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting my question.  I get what you're saying but your solution doesn't provide the result I was going for. I wanted a fixed spacing between cards, which I realize I forgot to specify.

Comment: What should the spacing between the cards be?